# Should I mention my future immigration status on my resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, hiring-process, recruitment, employment

I am at final stage of obtaining my US permanent residency (Green Card), hopefully within the next month or so.  My current employment contract will end in less than two months, and therefore, I need to apply for new jobs as soon as possible.  Due to the nature of my field, the GC is required to be considered for many jobs.

My question is whether it is fine (legal-wise) to mention that I will be a permanent resident (for example June 2016) on my resume.  The GC case is still in process, so it's neither approved nor rejected as of now. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure it'll be done within the next month? Would you expect your next employer to transfer your current visa if the GC isn't approved by that time?

Comment: Thanks for your answer JB. I am not sure as you may know better USCIS processing time is not very predictable but based on the recent USCIS approval trend, I should receive it this month. I do not expect to transfer my current visa (J-1) by the next employer.

Comment: Consider simply stating eligible to work in the United States and then explain the Green card situation after they are interested in you. I am going to say that a company that requires a green card may not hire you until you actually have one since Green Card approvals take notoriously long. But if they have already done the investigation steps and are in the final part of the process, they might be able to wait a month or two.

Comment: Thank you, HLGEM.  It sounds like a good idea.  Yeah, it seems I have no choice but to wait until the Card arrives and then apply for those positions.

Comment: What? No flood of mods calling this a legal question and shutting the thread down?

Comment: A resume is about the past - not the future. Just do not include it. Talk about it in the interview when you get that far

Comment: Thanks Ed for your answer.  I think this is what I am going to do.

Comment: @MrShA - I would also do that towards the end of the interview. By that point you can gauge if they are interested. It they are they will be able to help you or understand that little bump in the road

Answer (score 3):

**No. Don't include it.**

I am a native US citizen, and I have never felt the need to specify this on my resume. If you live in the US and are expected to be eligible to work, then I would not mention it until later in the interview process. A resume is designed to get you in the door - mentioning that you could possibly not have a green card in time is just a red flag that would put you below other candidates. You should certainly bring it up once there is an offer and before any background checks, but it doesn't need to be on the resume.

The only exception to this is if you are applying for a job in a country other than the one you live in. For example, if you live in India but are applying to jobs in the US, stating that you are already eligible (or soon will be) to work in the US would be beneficial.

Comment: Thanks David. Appreciate your answer.  In my field (aerospace), some sorts of US permanent residency proof (citizenship or the Green Card) is required to apply for many positions and get me at the door.  So basically, this is the first question I am being asked before even having an interview scheduled for me.  You are right about the exception.  However, I live and work in the US, so that exception doesn't apply to me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you accounting for the fact that this month ends with a few holidays like Christmas, Boxing Day and New Year's? Where I live in Canada, more than a few offices will be closed for a few days around that time of year and so anything to be processed may take longer because of those days.

While you could put that you are awaiting approval of your Green Card, this may be a bit of a yellow flag for some employers that may not want to have to go through the hassle of either transferring your visa or applying for a new one. I'd be more tempted to discuss this in interviews or once an offer is about to be presented rather than mention it early and be discarded right away as someone that may be "more trouble" in a sense. When I did work in the US, I had my visa all the time that I was working and made sure the paperwork was properly done. As you have adjusted your status, this would likely mean that it isn't worth discussing until the offer stage where you may have your card by that point in time.

Comment: Thank you, JB.  I am hopeful to have a decision by Christmas time but you are right, many governmental offices close early  during December. I will probably then have to wait to have the GC in hand to apply, or do not mention it at all.  I do have legal authorization permits  to work for any employer in the US, as I was able to file concurrently for adjustment of status (from non-immigrant to immigrant), so my visa status is valid throughout the process until I have a decision.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fine line here. On the one hand, you don't want to lie or tell them that there might be a problem with your work permission. On the other hand, work authorization is one of the very first things many employers will look at on your resume. Not having it, specially if your name sounds non-American might cause your resume to be rejected in the first screening process.

From what I understand, you are currently working legally in the US. Why don't you include something like "Work authorization: eligible for working in the US". If they contacted you again or invited you for an interview, you will have a chance to explain your situation in more details.

Comment: Thanks Ari for your reply.  You pretty much sum up my current situation.  I think this is a good idea to mention that I have the work authorization to work for any employer (not the GC) in the US, and if get further in the hiring process, I will explain the situation.